Response body isn't returned for a bad request when we use these specific special characters ^|[] in request parameter that accepts a hexstring only
I'm using .net core minimal api to build a project with few get endpoints. The get endpoint takes a request parameter named ID which is a hexstring i.e accepts only A-F and 0-9. So any special character used must return a 400 bad request error with a ProblemDetails response body.
I'm returning this response body for 400 error -
return TypedResults.ValidationProblem(
    errors: new Dictionary<string, string[]>{
                { "walletId", ["Wallet ID provided is invalid"] } 
            });

ID = ABCD^|[]1234
The problem here is that - when I run the project in my local , 400 status code along with the response body is returned, but when I send the request using deployment URL - I don't see any response body, just the 400 status code. The code is deployed on AWS with API Gateway and the returned URL is used for testing in postman.
Using all special characters except [ ] | ^ , returns a 400 bad request along with response body with both local URL and deployment URL.
I'm using the following code to validate regex
private static bool IsIdValid(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || !IsHexString().IsMatch(input))
        return false;
    return true;
}
[GeneratedRegex(@"^[A-F0-9]+$")]
private static partial Regex IsHexString();

deployment url - https://<someuri>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/get/{ID} ID is ABCD^|[]1234 actual - actual response expected - expected response
When ID is any of these ASDFGH!@#!^ ,  !##[[ , AHYTHG1#^]  , then the API throws the 400 error status code along with response object. (observation - whenever # is used before ^ or [ ] |, response body along with status code is returned with deployment url).
Is there something wrong with the deployment or just the special characters ^|[]  ?
